# Change title of Android app created using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: android, visual-studio-2017

I named my project (a Xamarin Forms project) something other than what  want now. I've searched this and other boards for an answer, and tried changing the name in many places. But when I run the project, the name for the app keeps using the name of the project. Is there a way to change this?

Thanks for any help,
Andy